# Why isn't the backspace working in a number field of a HTML5 contact form in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, php, web

I am trying to fix a JavaScript error related to a contact form. When the user is trying to enter their contact number they aren't able to correct it and they can't use the backspace key. This problem only comes up in Firefox, in Chrome, it is working completely fine.

Here is my code:

```
CG = (function(){
    var
    _isNumeric = function(evt){
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if(charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57)
            return true;
        return false;
    },
    _isDecimal = function(evt){
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if((charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) || charCode==46)
            return true;
        return false;
    },
    _alphanumeric = function(evt){
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        return ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123) || charCode == 8 || charCode == 32 || (charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57));
    };
    return{
        isDecimal:_isDecimal,
        isNumeric:_isNumeric
    }
});

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=text]").on("keypress",".isDecimal",function(e){
        return CG.isDecimal(e);
    });
    $(document).on("keypress",".isNumeric",function(e){
        return CG.isNumeric(e);
    });
    $(document).on("keypress",".alphanumeric",function(e){
        return CG.alphanumeric(e);
    });
    $(document).on("keypress",".isDecimal",function(e){
        return CG.isDecimal(e);
    });
})
```

Comment: Yes well if your functions return `false` the key event is ignored, so is backspace if you don't return `true` for it..

Comment: You could use HTML5 form validation without any JavaScript to make it simpler.

Comment: @xander could you please elaborate what I can do here

Comment: I just tested it myself and the first problem is not all browsers handle all keys with the "keypress" event, Firefox receives "backspace", but Chrome and IE does not (so the backspace press works in Chrome for example). But if you look at your code the `_isDecimal` already has an exception for the delete key (char code 46) `|| charCode==46`, so you can just add another exception for backspace there (char code 8) for a quick fix. Maybe not the best solution but that should work in your case,

Comment: Is there a specific reason to validate key presses instead of the input *contents*, such as trying to disable clipboard pastes?

Comment: @HemantNagori Xander is referring to this kind of thing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#Using_built-in_form_validation - for your case, you might benefit from the rules which allow you to check if the input is numeric (or just set the field as a "number" field in the first place), or verify whether it matches a specified regular expression. Much simpler than trying to manually detect keypresses etc.